# CN1: Change textcolor from second line of multibutton

Tags: java, codenameone

I want to change the textcolor of the second line from the multibutton. I am using the new GUI builder and I've created the multibutton programmatically.

I already tried it with different solutions like getting the text and then try to change the color. But I can't convert the String to a Multibutton so it's not possible to change the color of the text

```
Bestellungen bestellungen = new Bestellungen();
            bestellungen.getOrders();
        //Show orders in app
        Container conOrders = new Container(BoxLayout.y());
        conOrders.setUIID("conOrders");
        conOrders.setScrollableY(true);

        //Get elements from array
        for (int i = 0; i < bestellungen.getOrdersArr().size(); i++) {
            String order = bestellungen.getOrdersArr().get(i);
            String status = bestellungen.getOrdersStatusArr().get(i);

            MultiButton mb = new MultiButton(order);

            //TODO: CHANGE THE COLORS of line2
            switch (status) {
                case "completed":
                    //Change the second line to color green
                    mb.setTextLine2(status);
                    break;
                case "processing":
                    //Change the second line to color yellow
                    mb.setTextLine2(status);
                    break;
                case "cancelled":
                    //Change the second line to color red
                    mb.setTextLine2(status);
                    break;
                default:
                    mb.setTextLine2(status);
                    break;
            }

            conOrders.add(mb);

        }
```

If the String of status is "completed" then the TextLine2 text should be green and so on... Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use `setUIIDLine2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is `setUIIDLine2` then define the UIID in the theme to have the color you want.

However if you want direct control over the label color you can hack the container hierarchy. Notice that this is a bit of a hack and might change in future updates of Codename One.

It relies on the fact that a `MultiButton` is a container-component with child-controls and thus,
the second line (which is a label) can be accessed by climbing down the hierarchy.

There is only one small difficulty that is that the hierarchy depends on the
orientation. Thus, one has to differentiate both cases:

```
//  Vertical orientation
//
//  MultiButton
//      |    
//      |-- Container
//      |      | 
//      |      |-- Container
//      |      |      |
//      |      |      |-- Label (name=Line2)    <--- this one!
//      |      |      |-- Label (name=Line3)
//      |      |      |-- Label (name=Line4)
//      |      |
//      |      |-- Label (name=Line1)
//      |              
//      |-- Container
//      |      |
//      |      |-- Label (name=icon)
//      |  
//      |-- Container
//             |
//             |-- Button (name=emblem)
//
// ------------------------------------------------------------
//
//  Horizontal orientation
//
//  MultiButton
//      |    
//      |-- Container
//      |      | 
//      |      |-- Container
//      |      |      |
//      |      |      |-- Label (name=Line3)
//      |      |      |-- Label (name=Line4)
//      |      |
//      |      |-- Label (name=Line1)
//      |      | 
//      |      |-- Container
//      |      |      |
//      |      |      |-- Label (name=Line2)    <--- this one!
//      |      |      
//      |-- Container
//      |      |
//      |      |-- Label (name=icon)
//      |  
//      |-- Container
//             |
//             |-- Button (name=emblem)
//
private void setLine2Color(MultiButton multiButton, int color) {
    List<Component> childsLevel1 = multiButton.getChildrenAsList(false);
    Container firstContainerLevel1 = (Container)childsLevel1.get(0);
    List<Component> childsLevel2 = firstContainerLevel1.getChildrenAsList(false);
    Container targetContainerLevel2 = (Container)childsLevel2.get(multiButton.isHorizontalLayout() ? 2 : 0);
    List<Component> childsLevel3 = targetContainerLevel2.getChildrenAsList(false);
    Label firstLabelLevel3 = (Label)childsLevel3.get(0);
    firstLabelLevel3.getAllStyles().setFgColor(color);
}
```

I've tried several cases and it seems to work:

[image]

Thus, the following should work for you:

```
MultiButton mb = new MultiButton(order);

switch (status) {
    case "completed":
        //Change the second line to color green
        setLine2Color(mb, 0x00ff00);
        mb.setTextLine2(status);
        break;
    case "processing":
        //Change the second line to color yellow
        setLine2Color(mb, 0xffff00);
        mb.setTextLine2(status);
        break;
    case "cancelled":
        //Change the second line to color red
        setLine2Color(mb, 0xff0000);
        mb.setTextLine2(status);
        break;
    default:
        mb.setTextLine2(status);
        break;
}
```

Comment: Great work @topaco I added a slightly simpler approach